# How do I properly handle switch cases in combination with cucumber using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

I am trying to use a switch case in order to make a reusable test step using JavaScript.

However, cucumber suggests my step is undefined and I am not sure why.

The feature step in question is as follows:

When I search for "people" with name "characterSearch"

The code behind my feature is as follows:

```
When('I search for {string} with name {string}', async (type, name) => {
  switch(type) {
    case "planets":
      await searchFormPO.planetsRadioButton.click();
      break;
    case "people":
      await searchFormPO.peopleRadioButton.click();
      break;
    default:
      throw 'Please use planets or people as type input for this testcase.';
  }
  await searchFormPO.input.click;
  await searchFormPO.input.sendKeys(name);
  await searchFormPO.searchBtn.click();
});
```

The error shown when running my test is as follows:

```
   Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

     When('I search for {string}', function (string) {
       // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
       return 'pending';
     });
```

It suggests my code should be a function, which I've tried.
But my JS skills are a bit rusty, so I might be overlooking something.

I have tried googling switch cases in JS with cucumber but can't google my way out of this one.

Comment: How confident are you that Cucumber understands `async` functions (which always return Promises)?

Comment: I am not, I come from a Java background and JS's async handling in combination with cucumber is new to me.

Comment: Well it *might* understand asynchronous functions, but your function does not return anything (which would explain the `undefined` complaint).

Comment: I have just checked it against my passing async test steps and these also do not return anything but work just fine.
It is purely the one with the switch case that fails.

Comment: There's no possible way that a `switch` in a function like that would make it fail.

Comment: I have found the issue, it was using another feature file, causing it to fail since this feature file had steps in it that had no proper step attached to them.

I am sorry to have wasted your time.

All works well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine, the issue was in a wrongfully mapped older feature file.